# Plot a line (y = 2x + 7) on a graph

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, charts, graphing

I am working on a scientific calculator in C#. I have the parsing engine and such, now I would like to add a graph so the user can plot a line. Is there any kind of control that will let me input a function and it will graph a line in the chart? I'm not talking about plotting individual points by the way.

Take this linear equation in slope-intercept form for instance:

```
f(x) = 2x + 7
```

The main goal is to allow the user to write `2x + 7` in a textbox, and then it will graph the line. It would be preferable if custom functions could be used other than just linear functions, such as:

```
((x - 8) * 4^2)/(7.136 + x)
```

But it's not a requirement. Is there a third-party control for this? If not, how could I create such a control?

I have downloaded a program that graphs functions like this:

[image: Desktop Graphing Calculator]

How can I achieve this functionality in my Visual C# 2010 WinForms application?

Comment: You can [crudely] render such a graph yourself in native WinForms by handling the "Paint" event. Just step over each `x` (say, by increments of 0.01 for the above) to get the `y` (assume the function is defined as `float f(float x)` and the formula is hard-coded) - then draw a line between the `(x, f(x))` and `(prev_x, f(prev_x))`. Of course, it is better just to use an *existing* graphing control (it doesn't need to be commercial) - in any case, please *search* [first] for such existing solutions: google *and* codeplex are two good starting-points.

Comment: @pst I did search first, but I only got things such as business charts, nothing for graphing mathematical formulas.

Comment: This is the first one that popped up on google in my quick look: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25191/Graphic-Calculator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I searched for `mathematical function plot library for windows` and found this:

- [FPlot](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11608/FPlot-a-NET-library-for-plotting-functions-and-mea) a ".NET library for plotting functions and measurement data" (a project on CodeProject)

and you can try to use the source code of:

- [MathGV](http://www.mathgv.com/index.html)
- [Graph](http://sourceforge.net/projects/graph/files/Graph/)

You'll have to check the licenses.
I didn't try any of these, by the way.