# Trying to Draw a function

Tags: c#

I'm trying to draw a graph in c#, something like [image]

So far I've been able to draw simple lines using the `DrawLine`, but that is very limitative of its own, because, not only i'm forced to provide the start and end points, I'm also limited to straight lines.

And as you can see

[image]

I have a curve at the very last trech of the expression (a inverted parabola)

Any hints on how to perform this in a bmp drawing?

I've been drawing using the following

```
   using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
           { //g.DrawLine and others
}
```

Comment: I refer you to sinelaw's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14371085/plot-a-line-y-2x-7-on-a-graph

Answer (score 2):

You can use the similar function from the Graphics class `DrawCurve`. It takes an array of points as a parameter and will then draw through them. Depending on how accurate you want the curve, you can get the start point, end point and the turning point.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ak09y3z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: I will give it a try, but creating a array of points with those functions hmm.. seems it might need some tinkering

Comment: To add to the (correct) answer :There is also an overload which lets you controls the tension; very helpful! - Given a, my, and the two Tc and Td values, where would be the problem in creating a dozen or so points??

Answer (score 0):

The first step to drawing a function would be to evaluate it and save it to a Point array:

```
        //Create a Point array to store the function's values
        Point[] functionValues = new Point[100];

        //Calculate the function for every Point in the Point array
        for (int x = 0; x < functionValues.Length; x++)
        {
            //Set the every point's X value to the current iteration of the loop. That means that we are evaluating the function in steps of 1
            functionValues[x].X = x;
            //Calculate the Y value of every point. In this exemple I am using the function x^2
            functionValues[x].Y = x * x;
        }
```

Then, when you draw out the function, draw it like so:

```
        //Iterate through every point in the array
        for (int i = 1; i < functionValues.Length; i++)
        {
            //Draw a line between every point and the one before it
            //Note that 'g' is your graphics object
            g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, functionValues[i-1], functionValues[i]);
        }
```

When you are drawing, do it in the form's Paint event and make sure that the form is double buffered:

```
    Point[] functionValues;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
        this.Paint += Form1_Paint; //Subscribe to the Paint Event

        //Create a Point array to store the function's values
        functionValues = new Point[100];

        //Calculate the function for every Point in the Point array
        for (int x = 0; x < functionValues.Length; x++)
        {
            //Set the every point's X value to the current iteration of the loop. That means that we are evaluating the function in steps of 1
            functionValues[x].X = x;
            //Calculate the Y value of every point. In this exemple I am using the function x^2
            functionValues[x].Y = x * x;
        }
    }

    void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        //Draw using 'g' or 'e.Graphics'.
        //For exemple:

        //Iterate through every point in the array
        for (int i = 1; i < functionValues.Length; i++)
        {
            //Draw a line between every point and the one before it
            g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, functionValues[i - 1], functionValues[i]);
        }

    }
```

And lastley, to cause the form to update and repaint itself, call the Invalidate method of your form:

```
this.Invalidate();
```